# Jenkins: how to run task every 30 days

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins version is 2.235.5 (I should update it to next LTS version 2.249).

I configured Jenkins to run a job periodically every 30 days: Build Triggers → Build periodically → Schedule:

```
H 3 */30 * *
```

And now I see:

> Would last have run at Saturday, October 31, 2020 3:20:39 AM EDT; would next run at Sunday, November 1, 2020 3:20:39 AM EST.

[image: Jenkins Build Triggers → Build periodically → Schedule]

So it will be started again after 1 day, not 30 days…

How to run a job periodically every 30 days?

Update: history of Jenkins "predictions" for schedule above (job was created October 28):

> Would last have run at Thursday, October 1, 2020 3:20:06 AM EDT; would next run at Saturday, October 31, 2020 3:20:06 AM EDT.

> Would last have run at Saturday, October 31, 2020 3:20:39 AM EDT; would next run at Sunday, November 1, 2020 3:20:39 AM EST.

> Would last have run at Sunday, November 1, 2020 3:20:43 AM EST; would next run at Tuesday, December 1, 2020 3:20:43 AM EST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it's not practically possible. This [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/598141) is quite detailed.

> Jenkins used a [cron
> expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression), and
> the different fields are:
>
> ```
> MINUTES Minutes in one hour (0-59)
> HOURS Hours in one day (0-23)
> DAYMONTH Day in a month (1-31)
> MONTH Month in a year (1-12)
> DAYWEEK Day of the week (0-7) where 0 and 7 are sunday
> ```

cron syntax simply does not support every `n days`.

An impractical option wuld be to have a daily job with a [Conditional BuildStep](https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep/) to calculate if this day is n × 30 days from a given fixed day and abort if not..

But every 30 days doesn't really align w/calendar anyways, so is that really the intent?

Comment: I used this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536055/

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins- scheduled tab change syntax like...

. 30 * * * *

Example for understanding.... similar to cron job

Comment: Is this example to run job every 30 days?